# How to set item position to bottomcenter launchbackground.xml

Tags: android, xml, flutter, kotlin, splash-screen

I tried to add to my app splash screen an image but I don't know how to set the gravity of it to bottom center. There is my code :

```
<item
    android:width="265dp"
    android:height="160dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/bottomsplash"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

The bottom gravity set it at the bottom left but I want it to bottom center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`android:gravity="bottom|center"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:width="265dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:height="160dp"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/bottomsplash"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```